# What Linux kernel version(s) have a fix for the L1TF (Foreshadow) exploit?

Tags: linux-kernel, cpu, intel

[Foreshadow is a new speculative execution exploit targeting Intel's SGX on Core chips](https://www.pcworld.com/article/3297419/security/foreshadow-l1tf-is-a-speculative-execution-exploit-targeting-intel-core-chips.html)

What Linux kernel version(s) contain a fix for the L1TF exploit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [LWN article on L1TF](https://lwn.net/Articles/762570/):

> The 4.19 kernel will contain the mitigations, of course. As of this writing, the [4.18.1](https://lwn.net/Articles/762571/), [4.17.15](https://lwn.net/Articles/762572/), [4.14.63](https://lwn.net/Articles/762573/), [4.9.120](https://lwn.net/Articles/762574/), and [4.4.148](https://lwn.net/Articles/762575/) updates, containing the fixes, are in the review process with release planned on August 16.

It is possible that some of the kernel versions will only contain partial fixes to the problems of L1TF.

But this is about the upstream kernel.

You should look at your distribution's vulnerability reports, since distributions have backported the fixes to their kernel packages.

For example:

- [USN 3740-1](https://usn.ubuntu.com/3740-1/) for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- [USN 3741-1](https://usn.ubuntu.com/3741-1/) for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- [RHSA-2018:2384](https://access.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2018:2384) for RHEL 7
- [CESA-2018:2384](https://lwn.net/Articles/762652/) for CentOS 7
- [DSA-4279](https://www.debian.org/security/2018/dsa-4279) for Debian

Look at your distribution's security advisories page to find more.

Comment: Since the question is about the kernel only, this answer is fine, thanks. It might be worth pointing out that other components may need fixing too, *e.g.* hypervisors ([XSA-273](https://xenbits.xen.org/xsa/advisory-273.html) for Xen). [Microcode updates](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/security-center/advisory/intel-sa-00161.html) are also available for some CPUs.

Comment: Thanks, I see L1TF mentioned for Ubuntu in this changelog: http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/l/linux/linux_4.15.0-32.35/changelog

Comment: Weirdly enough, nothing for Debian yet. Not even a DSA.

Comment: @Halfgaar Looks like it's just out: https://www.debian.org/security/2018/dsa-4279